# MySQL root password settings and sudo mysql VS mysql

Tags: server, mysql, sudo, password

My question may found duplicate as even I search a bunch of things, but as very much new to MySQL and little old to Ubuntu I am working on raspberry pi and trying to install the MySQL server to stretch image.

installing MySQL server using this:

```
 sudo apt install mariadb-server
```

By default, MySQL is installed without any password set up meaning you can access the MySQL server without any authentication.

With the MySQL server software installed to the Raspberry Pi, we will now need to secure it by setting a password for the “root” user.

Run the following command to begin the MySQL securing process

```
  sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

After this following things took place and I change the password and rest of the questions I said `y` and move ahead.

```
 In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current
 password for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and
 you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
 so you should just press enter here.

 Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
 OK, successfully used password, moving on...

 Setting the root password ensures that nobody can log into the MySQL
 root user without the proper authorisation.

 Set root password? [Y/n] Y
 New password: 
 Re-enter new password: 
 Password updated successfully!
 Reloading privilege tables..
 ... Success!
```

Now when I use the following command to access the MySQL server

```
 sudo mysql -u root -p
```

It asks for the password so I enter the password, which I entered as set above and it works.

But the strange thing is even I simply press enter after putting `sudo mysql -u root -p` it works.

And when I Put  `mysql -u root -p` it asks for the password which I entered as  set above and sadly this time it does not work and gave the error

```
    ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Can anyone help me why it is happening and where I am going wrong?

Comment: See this answer on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42742610

Answer (score 2):

The root user needs 'sudo'. Create new user with the following command:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

Now newuser can login without sudo requirement:

```
mysql -u newuser -p
```

Comment: `The root user needs 'sudo'.` This is not true. `mysql -u root -p` should work just fine.